# Manjaro Linux: Accidentally deleted boot partition. System is still running

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, manjaro

I just deleted the boot partition of my Manjaro OS by accident.
The OS is still running. Is there a way to restore the boot partition from the running state?
The current disk layout is:

```
    nvme1n1                                       259:0    0 465,8G  0 disk  
└─nvme1n1p2                                   259:2    0 465,5G  0 part  
  └─luks-940e32b1-7bd6-462c-8161-ad2eaa455f9a 254:0    0 465,5G  0 crypt /
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the partition was just deleted and you didn't create anything in its place, the data should still be there: it's just not referenced in the partition table.

`testdisk` is a tool that can find such partitions and recover them.

Alternatively, if you know exact location and size of the partition, you could create a new one in its place *but without formatting it*. If the newly created partition aligns perfectly with the filesystem on the deleted one, it will appear as if it was created on the new partition.

On GPT-partitioned disks, restoring the UUID of the original partition may not be possible. You may have to update `fstab` and initramfs to match the new partition. Alternatively, you can alter partition's UUID to match `fstab`.

Comment: Testdisk is a very good suggestion! I will go that route, boot into windows and access the linux drive from there. Thank you!

Comment: It works natively on Linux too. Keeping the system running until you're done may be a good idea. Alternatively, use a live media. GRML comes with testdisk included, I think.